# I am unable to print the value of onChange

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import styles from "./inputMask.module.scss";
import { Controller, useFormState } from "react-hook-form";

const TimerInput = ({
  src,
  label,
  type,
  step,
  name,
  control,
  required,
  style,
  placeholder,
  showCurrencyMask,
  onChange
}) => {
  const state = useFormState({ control, name });
 

  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        rules={{ required: required }}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <div className={styles.inputBox} style={style}>
            <label className={styles.title}>{label}</label>
            <div className={styles.inputMaskDiv}>
              <img className={styles.inputImg} src={src} />
              {showCurrencyMask ? (
                <InputMask
                  className={styles.inputMask}
                  type={type}
                  name={name}
                  step={step}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  mask="9.99 €"
                  maskChar="0"
                  alwaysShowMask
                  onChange={onChange}
                  {...field}
                />
              ) : (
                <InputMask
                  className={styles.inputMask}
                  type={type}
                  name={name}
                  step={step}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  {...field}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimerInput;
```

Here is my component and here is my parent component where I am using it

```
<div className={styles.quantity}>
  <TimerInput
    src={Percentage}
    type={"text"}
    label={"DISCOUNT"}
    style={{ width: "120px" }}
    name={"discount"}
    onChange={handlePercentage}
    control={control}
  />
</div>
```

```js
const handlePercentage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value); 
};
```

I have passed the `onChange` in my component and also tried passing an arrow function inline directly to the `onChange` prop of the `TimerInput` component but it did not work. This can sometimes cause issues with certain libraries or components that expect a function reference instead of a new function instance on each render.

Comment: Can you specify what the problem is ? Is is that onChange isn't triggered when it should be ? Or is it that handlePercentage isn't called ? Or is it something else ? "it did not work" isn't specific enough, give us what you have and what you expect please

Answer (score 0):

the order of onChange should change try to change it with {...field} because the field object contain also onChange it override your onChange
so you need to do : <

```js
<InputMask
                  className={styles.inputMask}
                  type={type}
                  name={name}
                  step={step}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                   {...field}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
```